# Vim ~/.vimrc au! FileChangedShell

Tags: vim, arch-linux

I put this command in ~/.vimrc.

```
au! FileChangedShell img.dat | r img.dat
```

which also contains

```
set autochdir           " pwd is always directory of current buffer
```

I hoped to ensure that, if the file img.dat exists in pwd and it is modified by some app other than vim, then vim would read the new img.dat into the current buffer. It does not, nothing happens.

```
v:fcs_reason is unset  
:if exists("#FileChangedShell") | echo 'yes' | else | echo 'no' | endif
```

returns 'yes'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `:edit` command instead of the `:read` command.  But the `:edit` command would fail if you had unsaved changes in Vim, so you have to force it with a `!`.  Also, I don't know why you have a `|` preceding the command, as it doesn't belong there.

Try this:

```
au! FileChangedShell img.dat e!
```

**Edit:**  Note that FileChangedShell does not immediately trigger every time a file on disk associated with a Vim buffer changes.  There are specific times Vim checks for a changed file. From `:help FileChangedShell`:

> Mostly triggered after executing a shell command, but also with a `:checktime` command or when Gvim regains input focus.

I believe it also happens when you ask Vim to write the file.

Comment: No, I need r.  The | was a leftover from actually having 'echo v:fcs_error | r img.dat' which I did not completely delete.  au! FileChangedShell r does not work either.  Think I'll post this question to the vim mailing list.  Thanks for your help.